# Introspect referenced type of an annotated class

Tags: java, gradle, reflection, annotations, annotation-processing

I'm developing an annotation processor aiming to generate code by introspecting annotated class return types methods.
I have 2 modules:

- app: containing my annotated classes
- processor: containing my annotation and the relative processor

These are my gradle files:

**app/build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

dependencies {

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2'

    implementation project(':processor')
    annotationProcessor project(':processor')
}

compileJava {
    options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.annotationProcessor
}
```

**processor/build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2'
}
```

**settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'MyProject'
include('app')
include('processor')
```

I have this annotation (processor module)

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface MyAnnotation {

}
```

This is an annotated class

```
@MyAnnotation
public class DogGenerator {

    public Dog getDog() {
        return new Dog("Brutus");
    }
}
```

This is my processor

```
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_11)
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("com.myann.MyAnnotation")
public class MyAnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    private Filer filer;
    private Messager messager;
    private Elements elementUtils;

    @Override
    public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv) {
        super.init(processingEnv);
        filer = processingEnv.getFiler();
        messager = processingEnv.getMessager();
        elementUtils = processingEnv.getElementUtils();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {

        final Set<? extends Element> elementsAnnotatedWith = roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(
                MyAnnotation.class);

        for (Element annotatedElement : elementsAnnotatedWith) {
            if (annotatedElement.getKind() != ElementKind.CLASS) {

                messager.printMessage(Kind.ERROR, "Only classes and method can be annotated with " + MyAnnotation.class.getSimpleName(), annotatedElement);
                return false;
            }

            TypeElement typeEl = elementUtils.getTypeElement(annotatedElement.asType().toString());
            final Element method = typeEl.getEnclosedElements()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(o -> o.getKind() == ElementKind.METHOD)
                    .findFirst()
                    .get();

            TypeMirror returnType = ((ExecutableElement)method).getReturnType();
            messager.printMessage(Kind.WARNING,"return type " + returnType.toString());

        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

With this code I'm able to print the return type `com.myann.Dog`, but how can I introspect it in order to get its fields or methods?

If I try to load the class with `Class.forName`, I receive a `ClassNotFoundException`.
If I add `app` module as a dependency of the `processor` module I hit a circular dependency error.

Comment: How about using the same method you already used in the code, `elementUtils.getTypeElement(…)`?

Comment: @Holger you are right, I don't know why I didn't try that way XD thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with, ymmv:

```
for (TypeElement tEl : annotations) {
  for (Element el : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(tEl)) {
    // .. put yer code 'ere arrrr
  }
}
```